# How does the strlen function work internally?

Tags: c, strlen

How does `strlen()` work internally? Are there any inherent bugs in the function?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`strlen` usually works by counting the characters in a string until a `\0` character is found. A canonical implementation would be:

```
size_t strlen (char *str) {
    size_t len = 0;
    while (*str != '\0') {
        str++;
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

As for possible inherent bugs in the function, there are none - it works exactly as documented. That's not to say it doesn't have certain problems, to wit:

- if you pass it a "string" that doesn't have a `\0` at the end, you may run into problems but technically, that's not a C string <sup>(a)</sup> and it's your own fault.
- you can't put `\0` characters within your string but, again, it wouldn't be a C string in that case.
- it's not the most efficient way - you could store a length up front so you could get the length much quicker.

But none of these are bugs, they're just consequences of a design decision.

On that last bullet point, see also [this excellent article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) by Joel Spolsky where he discusses various string formats and their characteristics, including normal C strings (with a terminator), Pascal strings (with a length) and the combination of the two, null terminated Pascal strings.

Though he has a more, shall we say, "colorful" term for that final type, one which frequently comes to mind whenever I thing of Python's excellent (and totally unrelated) f-strings :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> A C string is defined as a series of non-terminator characters (any character *other* than `\0`) followed by a terminator. Hence this definition disallows both embedded terminators *within* the sequence, and sequences *without* such a terminator. Or, putting it more succinctly (as per the ISO C standard):

> A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.