# How do i cycle through each letter in a string?

Tags: c, string, ascii

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    char msg[31] = {'\0'};
    char encrypted[31] = {'\0'};
    int key;


    printf("Please enter a message under 30 characters: ");
    fgets(msg, 31, stdin);

    printf("Please enter an encryption key: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);

    int i = 0;

    while (msg[i] && ('a' <= msg[i] <= 'z' || 'A' < msg[i] < 'Z'))
{
    encrypted[i] = (msg[i] + key);
    i++;
}

    printf("%s\n", msg);
    printf("%d\n", key);
    printf("%s\n", encrypted);

}
```

Okay i've got my code to increment the characters but i don't know how to make it ignore special characters and spaces. Also how do i use `%` to loop back to `'a'` and `'A'`?

Thank you.

Comment: If your key is an `int`, what happens if you would increase the character's value beyond the limits of the `char` type?

Comment: if a person enters an integer of like 28, instead of going past 'z' it will loop back to 'a' and add 2 more to get to 'c'.

Comment: ASCII represents more than just letters - watch out!

Comment: You're doing a rot13 type of cipher?

Comment: yes, it is a rot13 type cipher

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` and `fgets` seem fine in this situation the way you've used them.

In C, a string is just an array of characters.  So, you access each element using a `for` loop and array indexing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
  char thisChar = str[i];
  //Do the processing for each character
}
```

You can perform arithmetic on `thisChar` as necessary, but be careful not to exceed 255.  You might want to put a check on `key` to ensure it doesn't get too big.

Comment: It would be a better idea to precompute `strlen`, because, as I understand, `strlen` is `O(n)` EDIT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132849/strlen-in-c-and-c-how-does-it-work

Comment: Fair comment, although I don't think speed is a priority here - Premature Optimisation and all that :)

Comment: True enough. The code probably won't be slow, but if it is, the O(n^2) will be the cause... however, n < 31, so no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

1. You just need a simple `for` loop:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
   {
       // operate on msg[i]
   }
   ```

   If you didn't know the length of the string to begin with, you might prefer a `while` loop that detects the null terminator:

   ```
   int i = 0;
   while (msg[i])
   {
       // operate on msg[i]
       i++;
   }
   ```
2. Your `fgets` and `scanf` are probably fine, but personally, I would be consistent when reading input, and `fgets` for it all.  Then you can `sscanf` to get `key` out later.

Comment: That would work, too.  It's just a bit non-idiomatic for a beginner, I think.

Comment: Okay i've done that and i've got it to increment. But now theres another problem. How do i make it so that spaces and special characters don't increment. Also how do i get letters to loop back to 'a'. I've tried this: while (msg[i])
{
    if ('a' <= msg[i] <= 'z' || 'A' < msg[i] < 'Z')
    {
    encrypted[i] = (msg[i] + key);
    i++;
    } else {
    i++;

Comment: The comparison operators don't stack up like that.  You need `if ((msg[i] >= 'a') && (msg[i] <= 'z'))`, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a string from scanf:

```
char msg[31];
scanf("%30s", msg);
```

OR (less efficient, because you have to fill the array with 0s first)

```
char msg[31] = { 0 };
scanf("%30c", msg);
```

Iterating a string is as easy a for loop (be sure to use c99 or c11)

```
int len = strlen(msg);
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    char current = msg[i];
    //do something
    msg[i] = current;
}
```

"Encrypting" (i.e. ciphering) a character require a few steps

1. Determine if we have an uppercase character, lowercase character, or non-alphabetic character
2. Determine the position in the alphabet, if alphabetic.
3. Update the position, using the modulus operator (%)
4. Correct the position, if alphabetic

I could give you the code here, but then you wouldn't learn anything from doing it yourself. Instead, I encourage you to implement the cipher based on the steps I provided above.

Note that you can do things like:

```
char c = 'C';
char e = 'E' + 2; 
char lower_c = 'C' - 'A' + 'a';
```

Comment: thanks, i've got the code to increment the key but now im stuck on using modulus to loop back to a or A and i also don't know how to get it not to increment special characters and spaces. I've done this and it still doesn't work. while (msg[i])
{
    if ('a' <= msg[i] <= 'z' || 'A' < msg[i] < 'Z')
    {
    encrypted[i] = (msg[i] + key);
    i++;
    } else {
    i++;
    }
}

Comment: Try handling uppercase separate from lowercase. Also, `'a' <= msg[i] <= 'z'` isn't valid, but `'a' <= msg[i] && 'z' >= msg[i]` does. The reason you need to handle upper & lower separately is because uppercase have a value of about 30 more than lowercase.

Comment: @NeXtMaN_786 Also, you'll need to get the character between 0-25, add your key, then modulus, then get it back to a character. That's why you have to handle upper and lower case separately -- because you subtract different numbers to get them 0-25.