# Why Null character does not adds up to the end of string when scanf'd?

Tags: c, string, strtok, strlen

```
--start of snip--
char name[15];
...

printf("Enter employee name \n");
scanf("%s",name);

printf("strlen %d \n", strlen(name));
--end of snip --

Output:
Enter employee name
Veronica
8
```

why is it not adding null character to the end !? am i missing anything?

Please someone explain.

**Edited:**

Was reading line from opened file using `fgets` and used `strtok(line,"\t ")`
to get the tokens from the line.

```
--snip--
char * chk;
char line[100];
char temp_name[15];
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, filep))
{
      chk = strtok(line, " \t");
      while(chk !-= NULL)
      {
           strcpy(temp_name, chk);
           chk = strtok(NULL, " \t");
      }
}
--snip --
```

**Problem:**

I am guessing extra character is getting added to the end of the temp_name(not just the name) due to improper handling in strtok delimitter usage.

**solution:**

```
if(!strncmp(temp_name, name, strlen(name))) // this is one fix
```

Other wise use

```
sscanf(line, "%s", temp_name); //easy fix
```

Anyways I was confused whether there is problem with NULL or extra character getting added to in strtok operation.

thanks for the answers.

Further, if any one would like to help out what delimiter should i use in strtok to avoid any space, tab etc.

Comment: It's there. `strlen` does not count it .

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132849/strlen-in-c-and-c-how-does-it-work

Comment: If it wasn't there, strlen wouldn't be able to measure the string

Comment: Also be careful with `scanf`. What happens if usr enters a string with more than 15 chars?

Comment: @Johnny stack overflow would happen, and i would need to put a fix there, right!? Or any better handy solution is there other than putting a check!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NUL terminator character is added, but strlen returns the length of the string without its NUL terminator.

Answer (score 2):

From [`man 3 strlen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html) :

> The strlen() function calculates the length of the string s, **excluding
>   the terminating null byte ('\0')**.

Answer (score 0):

Its there, Null will be added to array at the end of scanf.
strlen function will give you number of characters till NULL.It doesn't count NULL during string length calculation